# How do I clear the entire contents (rows) from a .net ListViewCollections object?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a ListViewCollection defined in my .Net C# application.

Currently, when assigning to it, we are simply creating a new object.

```
var ItemsView = new ListViewCollection(items);
```

I would like to be able to preserve the column sorting on the ListViewCollection object.

Is there a way I can simply clear the entire contents (rows) of the ListViewCollection object and add new contents (rows)?
I assume that this would persist any of the previously defined column sorts.

Thanks

Comment: `ItemsView.Clear()`?

Comment: MB: I would ave the itemsView.Clear() as well, but it does not come up in intellisence in Visual Studio. Am I missing and additional reference/assembly perhaps?

Comment: do you mean a ListCollectionView? As far as I know you normally do not work on them. You implement them for sorting/filtering a normal IList implementing collection. So you would need to clear the underlying collectioin instead of ListCollectionView. However you can remove the entries (one by one) with the Remove method

Comment: Assuming `ListCollectionView` is correct, `(ItemsView.SourceCollection as IList).Clear();` should do it.